# How can I convert the following code about CGContext into Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, cgcontext

Just like the headline ,I have some Objective-c code ,how can I use them in Swift3

```
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
NSMutableAttributedString *attri = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:_text];
[attri addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] range:NSMakeRange(0, _text.length)];

CTFramesetterRef ctFramesetting = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)attri);
CTFrameRef ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctFramesetting, CFRangeMake(0, attri.length), path, NULL);
CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context);

CFRelease(path);
CFRelease(ctFramesetting);
CFRelease(ctFrame);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clean `Swift 3` version:

```
context.saveGState()
context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity
context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

let path = CGMutablePath()
let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
path.addRect(rect, transform: .identity)

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: _text as String)
attrString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName,
                        value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0),
                        range: NSRange(location: 0, 
                                       length: _text.length))

let ctFramesetting = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString)
let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctFramesetting, 
                                       CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), 
                                       path, 
                                       nil)
CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context)
```

I advise you **not to use converters**.

**Why?** 
With converters you'll

- probably use variables where you need constants
- bridge/cast values
- explicitly unwrap optionals
- break Swift style (this depends on what style you use actually, but still)
- break language conventions

this means you'll get unstable/dirty code that you need to refactor

Comment: speaking about style, you should probably keep some consistency. If you wrap after `x` and `y` in `CGRect`, you should wrap after `width`, too. The same for `transform`. It's not a bad idea to wrap directly after the opening `(` and put `)` on the last line, the same we are doing with blocks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like the [Objective-C to Swift Converter](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/) to get code like the following:

```
context.saveGState()
context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity
context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
var path: CGMutablePathRef = CGMutablePath()
path.addRect(CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(size.width), height: CGFloat(size.height)), transform: .identity)
var attri = NSMutableAttributedString(string: _text)
attri.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(10)), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: _text.length))
var ctFramesetting: CTFramesetterRef? = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((attri as? CFAttributedStringRef))
var ctFrame: CTFrameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctFramesetting, CFRangeMake(0, attri.length), path, nil)
CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context)
```

But I would suggest that you do learn the underlying principles of both Objective-C and Swift so that you can do this sort of conversion yourself instead of relying on others or an external tool :)

For example, the above is the code as it came out from the converter. However, if you were to do some clean up, it would look something like this:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    return
}
context.saveGState()
context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity
context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
context.scaleBy(x:1.0, y: -1.0)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addRect(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height), transform:.identity)
let attri = NSMutableAttributedString(string:_text as String)
attri.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:10), range: NSRange(location: 0, length:_text.length))
let ctFramesetting = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attri)
let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctFramesetting, CFRangeMake(0, attri.length), path, nil)
CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context)
```

As you'll notice the following has to be added to get a `CGContext` instance:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    return
}
```

Also, some variables which were marked as mutable (or `var`) have been changed to immutable (or `let`) instances.

But that's not all there is to it. The above code assumes that `_text` is of type `NSString`. In order to use native Swift types, you should really change it to use `String` instead of `NSString`. Then the code changes to:

```
guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
    return
}
context.saveGState()
context.textMatrix = CGAffineTransform.identity
context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
context.scaleBy(x:1.0, y: -1.0)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.addRect(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height), transform:.identity)
let attri = NSMutableAttributedString(string:_text)
attri.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:10), range: NSRange(location: 0, length:_text.characters.count))
let ctFramesetting = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attri)
let ctFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(ctFramesetting, CFRangeMake(0, attri.length), path, nil)
CTFrameDraw(ctFrame, context)
```

So, in order to convert the code to Swift 3 and to make it work, you do need to understand the differences between Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: @BaQiWL you should use converters ONLY if your confident and will correct all the inaccuracies of the converter output. It's overall a bad practice. Besides this you'll grow faster and write better code if you'll write it yourself line by line and understand what's really happening

Comment: @OlehZayats If you read my comment after the conversion, I did advice him to learn how to do it on his own as well :) But if you know both Objective-C and Swift, a converter does the grunt work for you - as long as you know how to fix stuff afterwards.

Comment: @Fahim noticed, but still the right way to learn for a beginner is not to use converters. They save time and are useful if you're experienced but slow the learning speed if you're otherwise, don't you agree?

Comment: @OlehZayats Agreed, but honestly, then we would have to say "Go learn how to convert" to any beginner instead of giving them an answer at all since giving them the converted code at all is not much worse than giving them a converter - at least with a converter, they'd still probably have to learn some stuff before the code is useful, right? :)

Comment: @Fahim So let's give them "good" code example. And about examples...you know that 99% of beginners will just copy paste and celebrate that it's working...Still they totally need to learn "The Hard Way". To read the documentation\API ref about every line and write code not copy paste. But that's just my opinion. No offense ;)

Comment: @OlehZayats I agree with you in principle - unfortunately, I've been on SO for two years or so but only started answering questions the last week. Most people don't seem to care whether the answers are good or bad. And a lot of them don't seem to learn from the code either since I have given the same answer to the same person three, four times. Not a lot of people seem to want to learn and that's discouraging.

Comment: @Fahim Guess you're right. Same thing...Oh well, we can't change the need of an immediate answer with dirty working code for the majority of those who ask :(